# Algorithmicx package break under customized block

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algpseudocode

I have defined a new block called `Class` in the algorithmicx package. I want to insert a break within this new block for a new page but I'm getting an error:

> Package algorithmicx Error: Some blocks are not closed!!!.
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. \End

This is my minimum working example for reproducing the errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \algblock[Class]{Class}{End}
        \caption{Class: Part 1}\label{case_class_1}
        
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Class
            \Statex
            \Function{function 1}{ }
            \State do some stuff
            \EndFunction
            
            \algstore{bkbreak}

        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    % BREAK
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
        \algblock[Class]{Class}{End}
        \caption{Class: Part 2}\label{case_class_2}
        
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \algrestore{bkbreak}
            \Statex
            \Function{function 2}{ }
            \State do some stuff
            \EndFunction
            \End
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Errors:

> line 32: Missing number, treated as zero. \End
>
> line 33: Package algorithmicx Error: Some blocks are not closed!!!.
> \end{algorithmic}

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the error. The first error is `missing \documentclass`. Please provide the code of a small complete document, starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that *really* compiles and illustrates your problem

Comment: Apologies for the delay @gernot. Could you please have a look now? I've completed the minimum working example for reproducing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the new block in the preamble, instead twice in the `algorithm` environment. Besides, the `[h]` option for the second `algorithm` environment may be a problem if the second float overtakes the first one (which does not have the `[h]` option), as the `\algrestore` then might be executed before `\algstore`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algblock[Class]{Class}{End}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Class: Part 1}\label{case_class_1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Class
    \Function{function 1}{ }
    \State do some stuff
    \EndFunction
    \algstore{bkbreak}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
% BREAK
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Class: Part 2}\label{case_class_2}
  \begin{algorithmic}[h]
    \algrestore{bkbreak}
    \Function{function 2}{ }
    \State do some stuff
    \EndFunction
    \End
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't believe this was so elementary. Thanks a lot. This works just fine.